# bridge framework between to different version of spring

Tags: java, spring, frameworks

We have have an application who have a service and dao layer. It use spring 3.2

We started to create a new web application who use spring 4 (client side and controller).

What could be the best technology to communicate both application? Both are not on the same server.

I know there is spring remoting, but I don't know if it's still a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend exposing the service layer using contract first SOAP or REST web services.  They'll be reusable by any client that can make an HTTP request, including your new app.

Comment: so the web client would call directly the service layer?

Comment: the web client would make a web call to a soap or rest service.

Answer (score 0):

Spring remoting is a fine solution and only takes a few minutes get set up.